# What is the time complexity of my moveElementToEnd code?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

```
def moveElementToEnd(array, toMove):
    # Write your code here.
    for i in array:
        if i == toMove:
            array.append(array.pop(array.index(i)))
    return array
```

What are the time complexities of built-in function array.pop and array.index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(N^2)

Worst case you have to copy the entire array over (twice if pop has some bad optimizations) for every element that matches (possibly all).